# R: Lendo vários arquivos CSV e juntando todos em um só

Tags: r

Minha pesquisa consiste em analisar dados de vento de uma torre anemométrica. Nela os dados registrados pelo anemômetro são armazenados em um datalogger que escreve os dados em formato ".csv". Mensalmente eu faço o download dos dados e tenho dois anos de registro. Portanto, tenho na minha pasta 24 arquivos na minha pasta.

**Eu gostaria de ler e processar todos os arquivos ".csv" de uma única vez, gerando um único dataframe** para realizar as análises de todo o período de 24 meses. Até aí tudo bem, usei o código:

```
Wind <- list.files(path="mypath", 
                 full.names = TRUE, pattern = "^T1_Wind", 
                 recursive = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

O problema é que o datalogger escreve a primeira linha do cabeçalho dos arquivos ".csv" mensais de maneira diferente a cada nova leitura e mantém as demais linhas da mesma forma. Exemplifico os cabeçalhos de dois arquivos ".csv" baixados do datalogger:

Arquivo 1:

```
TOA5,"INVENTA_T1","CR6","8398","CR6.Std.07.02","CPU:Sonic_2D_etc.CR6","12521","Wind"
TIMESTAMP,"RECORD","v_x_l","v_y_l","v_x_u","v_y_u"
TS,"RN","m/s","m/s","m/s","m/s"
,"","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp"
2019-12-31 07:30:44,6,-0.6,-0.7,-0.4,0.8
2019-12-31 07:30:45,7,-0.5,-0.6,-0.4,0.8
2019-12-31 07:30:46,8,-0.6,-0.5,-0.5,0.6
2019-12-31 07:30:47,9,-0.6,-0.6,-0.5,0.7
2019-12-31 07:30:48,10,-0.7,-0.6,-0.2,1
2019-12-31 07:30:49,11,-0.5,-0.6,-0.4,1
2019-12-31 07:30:50,12,-0.5,-0.6,-0.4,0.9
2019-12-31 07:30:51,13,-0.7,-0.5,-0.5,0.8
```

Arquivo 2:

```
TOA5,"INVENTA_T1","CR6","8398","CR6.Std.07.02","CPU:Sonic_2D_etc_v2.CR6","12931","Wind"
TIMESTAMP,"RECORD","v_x_l","v_y_l","v_x_u","v_y_u"
TS,"RN","m/s","m/s","m/s","m/s"
,"","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp"
2021-04-27 11:36:30,7873854,-0.9,-0.5,-0.5,1.1
2021-04-27 11:36:31,7873855,-0.7,-0.4,-0.4,1.1
2021-04-27 11:36:32,7873856,-0.5,-0.3,-0.5,1.1
2021-04-27 11:36:33,7873857,-0.6,-0.1,-0.5,1.1
2021-04-27 11:36:34,7873858,-0.7,-0.1,-0.4,1
2021-04-27 11:36:35,7873859,-0.6,-0.3,-0.4,1
2021-04-27 11:36:36,7873860,-0.8,-0.3,-0.4,1.1
2021-04-27 11:36:37,7873861,-0.9,-0.4,-0.3,1.2
```

Notem que as primeiras linhas são diferentes e, dessa forma, o R merge os arquivos mas cria novas colunas de dados com o nome dos termos que são diferentes nos cabeçalhos dos arquivos e isso atrapalha completamente as análises, pois fica difícil reorganizar os dados. Vejam só como o R apresenta o resultado. Veja que ele criou duas colunas a mais, uma chamada "12521" e outra "12931":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver esse problema? Se eu conseguisse que o R usasse apenas a segunda linha dos cabeçalhos dos arquivos ".csv" para juntá-los no dataframe final seria ótimo, pois elas são iguais para todos os arquivos.

Podem me ajudar?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Leia os arquivos `csv` em dataframes (read.csv - veja o parametro `skip`). Junte os dataframes (rbind). Salve (write.csv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difícil responder adequadamente tendo postado seus dados apenas como imagens, mas parece que o cabeçalho correto está na segunda linha de cada arquivo (a primeira sendo informações do datalogger, a terceira e quarta com informações sobre as variáveis, como unidade de medida, e os dados começando na quinta linha).

Pode ler apenas o cabeçalho de um dos arquivos, depois carregar os arquivos pulando as primeiras linhas, usando o cabecalho salvo para os nomes das colunas.

```
# Gera arquivos de exemplo
texto <- c( "dados,irrelevantes,quaisquers", "x,y", "a,b", "c,d", "1,2", "3,4")
for (i in 1:3)  writeLines(texto, paste0("arquivo", i, ".csv"))

arquivos <- list.files(pattern = "^arquivo\\d.csv$")
```

Com R base:

```
cabecalho <- read.csv(arquivos[1], header = FALSE, skip = 1, nrows = 1)

dados <- lapply(arquivos, read.csv, header = FALSE, skip = 4)
dados <- do.call(rbind, dados)
names(dados) <- cabecalho

dados
#>   x y
#> 1 1 2
#> 2 3 4
#> 3 1 2
#> 4 3 4
#> 5 1 2
#> 6 3 4
```

Com tidyverse:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

cabecalho <- read_csv(arquivos[1], skip = 1, n_max = 0) %>% names

dados <- lapply(arquivos,
                read_csv, col_names = cabecalho, skip = 4) %>%
         bind_rows

dados
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     3     4
#> 3     1     2
#> 4     3     4
#> 5     1     2
#> 6     3     4
```

Comment: Carlos, muito obrigado pela resposta. Me desculpe por não ter colocado o arquivo editável, eu não sabia direito como fazer, mas agora coloquei as linhas editáveis dos arquivos "csv".

Comment: Carlos, o script funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!